# In Skyve how do I rename the OK button to something else e.g 'Save and Exit'

Tags: skyve

As per the title.

In Skyve how do I rename the OK button to something else e.g 'Save and Exit'.

I have a customer were what the "ok" button does is a bit unclear/confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the button labels per action definition.

```
        <ok displayName="Save and Exit" />
```

The OK button will only show when the user has access and the context is right, just like with

```
<defaults/>
```

To globally change the button label, open src/main/java/resources/i18n.properties (for all or any language variants contained within) and change the value assigned to

> resources.implicitActionName.ok

key.